# PHP dependency is 5.5 and the current running PHP is 7.2

Tags: php, moodle, php-extension

I'm facing an issue when installing Moodle in Centos 7. Moodle is based on PHP. So I installed PHP 7 and install the required extensions.

In the installation of Moodle, I get errors that extensions ZIP & Utl are not installed. I tried to install these 2 extensions, but the system displayed it is already there with the following line:

```
"Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.pit.teraswitch.com
 * epel: mirror.steadfastnet.com
 * extras: mirror.pit.teraswitch.com
 * updates: mirror.pit.teraswitch.com
Package matching php-common-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.
Nothing to do"
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: What commands did you use to try to install the extensions?

Comment: You said that the running PHP is 7.2, so you must install php72-zip or similarly named package.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the [IUS repo](https://ius.io/), from which you can get PHP 7.x packages that won't brick your system.
2. List all your currently installed PHP packages: `rpm -qa | grep ^php`
3. Delete them: `rpm remove php*`
4. Install the equivalent `php72u` packages, eg: `yum install php72u php72u-zip` etc